# How to skip method in step-into(F11)

Tags: c#, step-into

Lets take following example:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string MakeString(this object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return string.Empty;

        return obj.ToString();
    }
}

public class ABC
{
    public void Method()
    {
        object obj = default(object);

        //Implemention goes here..

        // Here every time in step into navigate to MakeString() Method.
        if(IsValid(obj.MakeString()))             
        {
            //Operations..
        }
    }

    private bool IsValid(string str)
    {
        //Check if string is valid or not..
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this example `Extentions` class having extention method and am using it in class `ABC` and when step-into in condition with this extention and other method call then every time I step-into in `MakeString()` method, can we skip it? By using `method attribute`? or by other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I mark a class as not my code so the debugger steps over it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951159/can-i-mark-a-class-as-not-my-code-so-the-debugger-steps-over-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [DebuggerStepThrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Attribute for this.